# dkim for email marketing service but none for email host

Tags: email, spam, microsoft-office-365, dkim, dns-zone

hopefully this is a simple question to answer...

For the last few years I've had only SPF setup with our O365 Exchange Online domain's DNS records.  I haven't yet setup a DKIM because we've never really had any issues with spam classification or NDRs.  But now that we've started to do some email marketing for the company and are looking at sending out a few thousand emails via ActiveCampaing, I think we need to add a DKIM.

If I add the ActiveCampaign generated DKIM for our naked domain (the one hosted on O365) but not an O365 recommended DKIM (yet), will this individual DKIM have any negative effect on legitimate outbound emails from our staff?

Yes, I know that I can have multiple selectors in one DKIM to authorise a bunch of sending services and should implement this, but I don't yet know how to do it, so for the moment I'm specifically asking about the single selector DKIM for ActiveCampaign even if it's temporary for the first day or so of this email marketing blast.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveCampaign like most 3rd party services nowadays has you covered.  By default messages they send are setup to DKIM.

> "All mail sent from ActiveCampaign will use ActiveCampaign's DKIM
>   signature by default. "

If you want to add one for your custom domains, you can enable it and generate the needed records from inside ActiveCampaign, take those and add to your DNS.

As you noted you can have multiple selectors, and those will be used for the respective services that utilize them.  So adding the selector for ActiveCampaign, won't add DKIM signing to your Office365 messages.

ActiveCampaign has a walk thru available on SPF, DKIM, and DMARC setup.  Currently available here:  https://help.activecampaign.com/hc/en-us/articles/206903370-DKIM-SPF-and-DMARC

If for some reason that link is dead just search for "ActiveCampaign SPF DKIM DMARC" -  https://www.bing.com/search?q=activecampaign%20spf%20dkim%20dmarc&qs=n&form=QBRE&pq=activecampaign%20spf%20dk&sc=0-21&sp=-1&sk=&cvid=9C519F4732484A34B62A5B4EA3C65919

Comment: Thanks.  I've read their FAQ article on SPF, DKIM and DMARC and have created the TXT DNS record with for the DKIM generated by their tool.  I did a test from ActiveCampaign to an address provided by mail-tester.com and the results look very promising.  It picked up the new DKIM entry.
I haven't made enabled DKIM Signing in Exchange on O365 still and the solo DKIM we have for the domain (which is the new AC one) doesn't appear to affect normal email delivery.  So this is all OK, or should I really add the two Microsoft DKIM CNAME records and turn on DKIM signing?